# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n-2}=1$

Tags: limits

> By epsilon-delta definition, show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n-2}=1$.

I start with $\left|\frac{n+1}{n-2}-1\right|=\left|\frac 3 {n-2}\right|$, but I don't know how to carry on. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\frac{n+1}{n-2} = 1+\frac{3}{n-2}$. Then $\left|\frac{n+1}{n-2} -1\right| = \left|\frac{3}{n-2}\right|$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N > 2+\frac{3}{\epsilon}$. Then if $n \ge N$, you have $\left|\frac{3}{n-2}\right|< \epsilon$.

To get a lower bound for $N$: We want $\left|\frac{3}{n-2}\right|< \epsilon$. This will be true if $3 < |n-2| \epsilon$, or equivalently $\frac{3}{\epsilon} < |n-2|$. Since we are interested in $n \to \infty$, we ask that $n$ satisfy $\frac{3}{\epsilon} < n-2$, or equivalently, $2+\frac{3}{\epsilon} < n$. So, if we pick $N > 2+\frac{3}{\epsilon}$, then if $n \ge N$, we will have the desired result.

Comment: But we don't know if n-2>0 ...

Comment: You do. Since $n \ge N$, you have $n-2 \ge \frac{3}{\epsilon} > 0$.

Comment: I get it, thanks

Comment: How do you think to choose that N?

Comment: I just worked backwards from the requirement $\frac{3}{n-2} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Can you show me the whole process of how you work backward please?

Comment: I added a paragraph to the end above...

Comment: Actually don't we have to consider all kind of value of n? Will there be problem if we just focus on n-2>0 ?

Comment: No. You just need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ that there exists some $N$ such that the above condition holds for $n \ge N$.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\left|\frac{3}{n-2}\right|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow n-2>\frac{3}{\epsilon}$, so you just need to choose $n>\left\lceil{2+\frac{3}{\epsilon}}\right\rceil$.